# MongoDB C# Driver query always returns null

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a simple query to mongoDB using C# Driver.
I've been trying a lot of things and then I came to this but it Always returns null.
Does anyone know if what could  it be?

```
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> users = Utilities.getCicCollection("Users");
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filter= builder.Eq("Username", "test@test.it") & builder.Eq("Password", "testing");
            var result = users.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
            return (result!=null?true:false);
```

Comment: @MachineLearning Yes, there is an user with the username and the password specified. I'm using the same query(translated) with MongoBooster to check.

Comment: @MachineLearning Already tried to do something like "\@" but it didn't work.

Comment: it would be all standard like in the documentation for the [Logical AND](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/#logical-and) if it were `_database.GetCollection`, so my next question is: pls share `Utilities.getCicCollection`

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard snippet

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("Username", "test@test.it") & builder.Eq("Password", "testing");
var list = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync()
var result = list.FirstOrDefault();
```